# Why is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorpic to $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt[4]{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I would suggest this is true since a isomorphism exist, namely
$\phi:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}) \to \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt[4]{2}), \sqrt[4]{2} \mapsto i\sqrt[4]{2}$. But is it true that this is a homomorphism?

Comment: Yes it's a homomorphism, or to be pedantic it extends to a unique homomorphism. To show that it is an isomorphism you need only show that it has an inverse, which is easy enough to find.

Comment: $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $i\sqrt[4]{2}$ are conjugates of each other

Comment: Defining $\phi$ at the one point is not enough to show it is a homomorphism.  How about claiming $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]3)$ are isomorphic by simply writing $\phi:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}) \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}), \sqrt[4]{2} \mapsto \sqrt[4]{3}$?  You need to add more to your argument.